# Decoding/Processing TTA Files Using Java

Tags: java, audio, decode, decoding

For a side-project to learn web development and database management I decided I to make a radio-like website using the vast amount of TTA audio files that I have (along with the Cue files that complement them).

However, the biggest hurdle over this project has been, well, handling the audio itself. I'm not really sure how to go about decoding the TTA files and using that information to utilize the Cues properly.

I've been all over the [Tau Projects](http://tausoft.org/wiki/Main_Page) website and just really at a loss on how to proceed. Some options I have considered, but not sure how they'd work/go about them.

---

**1. Audio Library that Supports TTA**

The easiest solution if one exists. From the very few audio libraries that exist for Java (at least that I know exist) none of them support the TTA format. If I am mistaken, please correct me.

---

**2. Using JNI/JNA to Hook into Decoders**

The Tau Projects has a list of [downloads](https://sourceforge.net/projects/tta/files/tta/) for various plugins and I assume implementations for encoders/decoders (like ttaenc-win). Now I do not know much about anything for C/C++ so this may come as a challenge for me to use. From what I can understand about the libtta++ download is it's just a bunch of interfaces. I can only assume that the ttaenc-win is just an implementation of this (it's only a .exe file so not too sure). If one of the downloads is an implementation of these interfaces then I can use JNI/JNA to hook into them and process the audio that way. If this is the case then it can work, but I just need some guidance.

---

**3. Using vlcj**

VLC supports the TTA format so it may be possible to use vlcj to process the audio that way. However, from my understanding on how vlcj works, it would create an instance of VLC every single time I want to use it (and would also require VLC to be installed). If this is true then this solution would be grossly inefficient and wouldn't scale at all even for a small amount of requests (as I assume I would need a new VLC instance for each user).

---

**4. Writing a Pure Java Implementation**

Being open source means the algorithm can very well just be natively made. But as I said earlier, I do not understand C/C++ code to make a Java-equivalent implementation and I'm not smart enough to decipher the information about the algorithm on the Tau Projects site (information can be found [here](http://tausoft.org/wiki/True_Audio_Codec_Algorithms) and [here](http://tausoft.org/wiki/True_Audio_Codec_Format)).

This solution would be by far the most lightweight, versatile, and portable option. If it can be achieved, this would probably be the route I'd like to pursue, but I would need guidance on it.

Comment: is this a funded project or what? If you point  to those C\C++ files straight I could take a look never heard TTA before  maybe someone has done it

Comment: The libtta and libtta++ are the files in question. libtta in particular has some C files that seem to have implementations, but my knowledge is severely lacking in that language to know otherwise. And yeah TTA is a rather obscure format, but it's the only one I can deal with at the moment.

Comment: both contain the lib file - can you extract the .c file? i could search but if you have the tool

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9sysGP4FUlyeUh0QmtkcUtTNlk

Comment: ok we reached  a point where we know this can be done - barring some surprise locked code etc and filter.h and other .h maybe needed - I expect someone with the other solutions will walk in.